# More informative error messages from a SQL server

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite.

When I execute a query, I get error messages such as "error near select" or "error near ','". I wish it would give me a line number or statement number.

After loading a trigger and encountering an error either in syntax or at run-time, I must go back to my editor and make changes. Then I have to execute a drop trigger command before reloading the trigger.

Is there a good SQLite browser or command line tool that provides more information than the one I am using?

Setting aside the implementation differences, would it make more sense for me to switch to mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different browser for SQLite wouldn't make that much of a difference since it would use the same library. Switching to MySQL in my experience is not a trade up in terms of error messaging, it's about the same or worse in my opinion. PostgreSQL, however (again in my experience), has much better error messaging, although it can at times be just as cryptic as MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: Sometimes I think MySQL only has this one error message: "*You have an error in your SQL syntax*"

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that not everything which works in postgres will work in sqlite as the supported dialect/amount of SQL is different. It shouldn't be a problem for simple queries.

Comment: @Sorpigal : true, but it seemd the OP was familiar with the reality of implementation differences, but true non the less!